# Include part title instead of chapter's on thesis headings

Tags: sectioning, thesis

I am using the MDT template for my thesis. I want to divide the document in parts (Introduction, Results, etc...), each one divided in different chapters. I would like to include the part title on headers instead of chapter's, but when I substitute "chapter" for "part" in \automark, it doesn't change it.

Code:

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \automark[chapter]{chapter}
    \ihead{\headmark}% Inner header
    \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
}
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
\ofoot{}% Outer footer
\pagestyle{thesisSimple}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{thesis}{%
    \automark*[chapter]{}%
}


\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{review}{%
    \ofoot[\shorttitle/\authorname]{\shorttitle/\authorname}
    \ifoot[\today]{\today}
}
\pagestyle{thesis}
\ifbool{headsepline}{\KOMAoption{headsepline}{true}}{}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\ClassError{\classname}{Package `fancyhdr' is
incompatible\MessageBreak with this class}{The pagesyles are defined 
    using package `scrlayer-scrpage', please consult the\MessageBreak 
KOMA-script documentation for details.}]{fancyhdr}
```

So I would like to include "1. Results" on headers instead of "Title of the first chapter of Results"

```
\part{Results}
\addchap{Title of the first chapter of Results}
\label{Results_1}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}


\section{Title of first section of first chapter of results}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

MDT template means MastersDoctoralThesis.cls? This class bases on the standard `book` class which does not provide `\partmark`. Therefore you have to set the marks manually using `\markright`, `\markboth` or `\markdouble`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\manualmark% <- switch to manual marks

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}\markdouble{\thepart.~Foo}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\part{Bar}\markdouble{\thepart.~Bar}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional remark:

KOMA-Script classes provide `\partmark`. If you switch to `scrbook`, then you can set `\automark[part]{part}`. But it changes the resulting document.

Example:

```latex
\providecommand\baseclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\AfterClass{scrbook}{\let\subject\relax}
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\automark[part]{part}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Foo}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\part{Bar}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]